# Haml not rendering element from rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I'm trying to render the appropriate element from my 'track' model which is a string in a column called 'genre'

However instead of rendering the genre; the page instead renders `=track.genre` instead of the actual genre. Is this a syntactical error?

index.html.haml (for views>tracks)

```
- content_for :header do
  %section.hero.is-warning
    .hero-body
      .container
        %h1.title
          Browse the newest Tracks
.instrument-index-grid.pt4
  - @tracks.each do |track|
    .track.border-light
      .track-thumb
        =link_to image_tag(track.image_url(:thumb)), track
        - if track.genre
          .condition
            %span.tag.is-dark = track.genre // this renders incorrectly
      .pa3
        %h3.fw7.f4.title= link_to track.name, track
        %p.has-text-gray.fg.pt1
          Sold by #{track.user.name}
        %p.f3.fw6.has-text-right.pt2.price= number_to_currency(track.price)
        - if track_artist(track)
          = link_to 'Edit', edit_track_path(track), class: "button is-small"
          = link_to 'Delete', track, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure ?" }, class: "button is-small"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a typo. Instead of

```
%span.tag.is-dark = track.genre
```

it should be

```
%span.tag.is-dark= track.genre
```

See the section "Ruby Evaluation" of the [reference](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html):

> = can also be used at the end of a tag to insert Ruby code within that tag

With your extra space after the tag, the `=` is no longer at the end of the tag, and it thus interpreted as plain text, together with the rest of the line.

Answer (score 1):

Move it to a separate line and remove space

```
.condition
   %span.tag.is-dark 
     =track.genre
```

Comment: Why did it render incorrectly previously? (this worked btw)

Comment: Most probably because you put it in the same line and surrounded `=` with spaces.